# java referencing Class<> as their subtype

Tags: java, class, inheritance, parameters, subclassing

I am trying to do something like this....

```
public class myClass2 extends myClass1
{
    @Override
     public void printStuff() { }
}

public class dostuff
{

   public dostuff() 
   {
        doSomething(myClass2.Class());
   }

   public void doSomething(Class<myClass1> cls)
   {
        cls.printStuff();
   }
}
```

Im getting compile errors like this

Required: myClass1
Found: myClass2

How can I tell the function to except subclasses of myClass1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void doSomething(Class<? extends myClass1> cls) 
{
    try {
      cls.newInstance().printStuff();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
      ....
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      ....
    }
}
```

1. To let the method expect sub-classes of `myClass1`, you have to use a bounded type parameter.
2. You have to create an instance of the class in order to call the method `printStuff()`.

You also have an error in `dostuff`. It should be :

```
   public void dostuff() 
   {
        doSomething(myClass2.class);
   }
```

Comment: why reflection is needed? Can't we create a object directly?

Comment: @user3218114 Of course you can create the object directly, but the OP wanted to pass the type of the instance to the `doSomething` method, and call the `printStuff` method for an instance of the passed type.